# Populate C++ model from external source in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I need to populate c++ model from a external source (for example USB). I have registered the model in main.cpp like this,

```
qmlRegisterType<HardwareDataModel>("org.example", 1, 0, "HardwareDataModel");
```

I need to change the private member of this HardwareDataModel class from the external source. Because I would like to change the the private data member of this model and fire signal to qml to change the UI. I got stuck how to proceed as I do not know how to populate those private data members. Do I need to instatiate HardwareDataModel in main.cpp? If yes, how to connect the instatiated HardwareDataModel object and one that is qmlRegisteredType (one shown above).

Comment: What is _private member_ and what do you mean saying _change it_? `qmlRegisterType` doesn't instantiate a type, it just make it available in QML. You should create it in qml: `import org.example1.0  HardwareDataModel {}`.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html#choosing-the-correct-integration-method-between-c-and-qml

Comment: @folibis, I tried to say that suppose I want to update a label dynamically using some AbstractItemModel in QML. So, I created model in QML and use the model's data in Label. The model's data will be updated after a while which will fire signal to update the Label. I do not know how to update the model data.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to describe the issue. Is `Label` delegate of a view using your model?

Comment: In short, how to update the model data.

Comment: You should inform a model that your data source has changed. [QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged).See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html) example.

Comment: @folibis. Thanks for your comment. I mean to say that how can I change the QAbstractItemModel class' data members (without qml firing signals or calling this model class). Then, when datamembers in this model, I do know it should emit signals to qml to update the ui.

Comment: Why don't you want to fire the signals?

Comment: @derM, I need to fire signal to update the label text.

Comment: That's correct. But you write: *(without qml firing signals or calling this model class)* - Why? Just fire them and you're good? I have not the slightes idea what it is you struggle with. You have an external source from which you read the data by some method (triggered by some interval or event), calculate a change set of the data, call the `beginInsertRows()` with arguments according to your change set, apply the changes to the underlying data structure, call `endInsertRows()`, maybe update the count property, and you are done. Where is now the problem?

Comment: @derM. What I mean to say was, QML should not request data i.e QML will not fire signal to C++. Instead, C++ model will be updated, and the function inside C++ should inform QML to update UI i.e C++ will fire signal to QML. Now, i have only registered the model in main.cpp as using qmlRegisterType. Also I cannot update the model, unless I fire signal to C++ from QML(which I do not want, I want model to update itself).

Comment: What is QML and what is C++ here? The Model is C++ but you create it in QML, is it now QML or C++? With creating the Model (no matter whether it is in C++ or QML) you also create it's connection to the backend. So it might have a member `UsbDeviceReader m_deviceReader` which reads from the device. And either this has a signal which will trigger the model data changes, or you also have a timer, which will trigger the read and the data changes. If it has dependencies you most likely can resolve them with a singleton factory.

Comment: You can also use another method of getting the model in QML, by creating it in C++ and setting it as context property... But that has already been discussed in the comments (see the comment from *NishantSingh*)